# React Native screen to add a city to a weather app using a REST API

Tags: interview-questions, react.js, rest, jsx, react-native

In a recruitment process, the company gives me a project to do in react native. I finished all the tasks. But company gave me a feedback and said that your project was good, but you did not **apply best practices for using rest api**. So we are not proceeding further with your application. I used redux with rest api. Below is the code of one screen. Please review it and suggest me how can I improve it

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {IconButton, TextInput, FAB} from 'react-native-paper';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import Header from '../components/Header';

function AddCityScreen({navigation}) {
    const [cityName, setCityName] = useState('');
    const API_KEY = '799acd13e10b7a3b7cf9c0a8da6e5394';
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const citiesReducer = city => dispatch({type: 'ADD_CITY', payload: city});

    const onSaveCity = () => {
      getWeatherOfCity(cityName);
      navigation.goBack();
   };
   const getWeatherOfCity = async city => {
      try {
         const result = await fetch(
       `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`,
        );

  if (result.status === 200) {
    const data = await result.json();
    citiesReducer(data);
  } else {
    Alert.alert('Error', 'Something went wrong while adding city', [
      {text: 'OK'},
    ]);
  }
} catch (ex) {
  Alert.alert('Error', 'Something went wrong while adding city', [
    {text: 'OK'},
  ]);
}
};
return (
  <>
  <Header navigation={navigation} titleText="Add a new city" />
  <IconButton
    icon="close"
    size={25}
    color="white"
    onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
    style={styles.iconButton}
  />
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      label="Add City Here"
      value={cityName}
      mode="outlined"
      onChangeText={setCityName}
      style={styles.title}
    />
    <FAB
      style={styles.fab}
      small
      icon="check"
      disabled={cityName == '' ? true : false}
      onPress={() => onSaveCity()}
    />
  </View>
</>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: '#fff',
   paddingHorizontal: 20,
  paddingVertical: 20,
},
iconButton: {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(46, 113, 102, 0.8)',
  position: 'absolute',
  right: 0,
  top: 40,
  margin: 10,
},
title: {
 fontSize: 24,
 marginBottom: 20,
},
text: {
  height: 300,
  fontSize: 16,
},
fab: {
 position: 'absolute',
 margin: 20,
 right: 0,
 top: 150,
 },
});

export default AddCityScreen;
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/263431/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure what they could mean here with "applying rest api best practices". Maybe they mean not exposing `API_KEY` and storing this using something like [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain). Either way the variable could be defined outside the functional component scope. Apart from that I don't really see much wrong with what you've shown. Are you sure they found problems with this code specifically and not in some other piece of code?

Answer (score 4):

The first mistake: API key is public maybe you could store it in react-native-keychain.

Secondly, you should create three files for style(component), for view(component), for function(API&(component)).
Then in the view component, you will import the style file and function file that have all algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good and clean but as per my evaluation following things should be taken care of

- There should be folder structure for Component, Actions, Routers(APIs), Screens etc.
- There should be common API class to handle responses like code 401(Unauthorized), 500(Bad Gateway), etc.

Hope this is helpful